# Codeigniter passing variable error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter and having problem to send variable using the 
    **$this->load->view('signup',$data)**.

This is some code in my controller.

```
function create_member()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('signup');
    }else
    {
        $this->load->model('membership');

        if($query=$this->membership->check_username() == TRUE)
        {
            $data['msg']= "Username exist";
            $this->load->view('signup',$data); //problem encounter here.

        }else
        {
            if($query = $this->membership->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
            }else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here the error message :
**A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: msg

Filename: views/signup.php

Line Number: 99**

```
<?php echo $msg; ?> // code inside view/signup.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're code is getting into this block and you're not setting `$data['msg']` in here so in the view it doesn't exist.:

```
else
        {
            if($query = $this->membership->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
            }else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');
            }
        }
```

Either initalize `$data['msg']` to null at the beginning of your method, or do a check in the view to see if it exists.

Comment: Thanks,you were right,i have to initalize $data['msg'] to null at the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('signup');
}
```

You're loading the view without passing any variables, so `$msg` won't be set.

You need to add `isset($msg)` to the view (or `$data['msg'] = ''` to the controller).